# ORACLE - Exporting Procedures / Packages to a file

Tags: oracle, file, export, database, procedure

I would like to programmatically  export my Procedures / Functions and Packages into individual files (as a backup) and using Oracle 9.2.

The closest solution i found was using DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL , but how do i output the CLOB to a text file, without losing any parts (due to length or indentation) ?

Or maybe do you have other  solutions to backup packages or other functions individually (only the one i want, not all of them) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to get CLOBS (and LONGS) from command line utilities like SQL*Plus always seems  to give me formatting/truncation problems.  My solution was to write a simple utility in a non- type checking language (Perl) that uses `DBMS_METADATA` to bring the CLOB back into a string.

Snippet:

...

```
$sthRef = $dbhRef->prepare("select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(?,?) from dual");

$sthRef->execute('PACKAGE', $thisName);

while (($thisDDL) = $sthRef->fetchrow()) {

  print $thisDDL;

}

$sthRef->finish;
```

...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the DDL, there really is no way except `DBMS_METADATA` like you already said.

Usually, this kind of a backup is done with `exp` (or `expdp`), although this doesn't create a SQL file like you would get with most other DBMS systems.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET pages 0
spool proclist.sql
SELECT
CASE line
WHEN 1 THEN
'CREATE OR REPLACE ' || TYPE || ' ' || NAME || CHR(10) || text
ELSE
text
END
FROM user_source
WHERE TYPE IN ( 'PROCEDURE','FUNCTION')
ORDER BY name, line;
spool OFF
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks goes for RAS ,  guest for his answer ,
I needed to get codes for some procedures only, so I tried the code , to find that this code truncate the code after procedure name in first line of the code and replace it with three dots '...'

so I changed the code to the following:

```
   SELECT CASE line
      WHEN 1 THEN 'CREATE OR REPLACE ' -- || TYPE || ' ' || NAME || --CHR(10) || ' (' 
            || text
   ELSE
      text
   END
   FROM user_source
   WHERE TYPE IN ( 'PROCEDURE') and name like 'SomeThing%'
   ORDER BY name, line;
```

and this page
[export procedures & triggers](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_export_stored_procedures_triggers.htm)
have a very usefaul code:

```
   connect fred/flintstone;

   spool procedures_punch.lst

   select
      dbms_metadata.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE',u.object_name)
      from
      user_objects u
   where
      object_type = 'PROCEDURE';

   spool off;
```

Final way to do it by using Toad Schema Browser , then select all the needed procedures and mouse right click then select export from the menu.